# Understanding the total number of possibilities w/ at least

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I'm having difficulty understanding a problem when they give the length and say AT LEAST x amount of numbers or letters.

For example: (Includes case sensitive letters and numbers)

Length 8 at least 2 numbers. Answer:  $62^8 -52^8 -(52^7)(10)(8)$

What does each part or section in that answer represent? I know $62^8$ represents the total combination but when we start to subtract out the other portions, I get confused.

Another problem:

Length 5 at least one repeated character. Answer: $62^5 -62*61*60*59*58$

If you could explain your thought process during the problem, that would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First problem: $52^8$ is the number of strings with $0$ numbers ($8$ letters). $52^7 \cdot 10 \cdot 8$ is the number of strings with $1$ number and $7$ letters. There is an extra factor $8$ because the number can be at each of the $8$ positions.

Second problem: $62 \cdot 61 \cdot 60 \cdot 59 \cdot 58$ is the number of strings without repeating characters. There are $62$ possibilities for the first character, $61$ for the second, etc.